# Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing the list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to delete a list item in **OnItemClick** method. DB is called for this purpose and item is getting deleted. But after that my list view is not refreshed, unless and until I called that activity again. Also, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged isn't working. Help Please. I have spent hours trying different solutions but none is working.Thanks!

```
package com.fyp.digitalsecretary;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.widget.Button;
//import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class UpcomingReminderList extends Main implements OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView                    upcomingReminderListView;
    private ArrayList<ReminderItem>     tasksArrayList ;
    private DynamicListAdapter          upcomingReminderListAdapter;
    private ReminderItem                tempReminder;
    public static android.app.ActionBar actionBar ;
    private Context                     c;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.upcomming_tasks);      
        Main.actionBar.setTitle("Upcoming Tasks");              
        tasksArrayList = DBHandler.getInstance(this).getBothReminders();

        upcomingReminderListAdapter = new DynamicListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),tasksArrayList);
        upcomingReminderListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTasks);

        upcomingReminderListView.setAdapter(upcomingReminderListAdapter);
        upcomingReminderListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        upcomingReminderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        tempReminder = tasksArrayList.get(position);
        AlertDialog.Builder list = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final String[] dept = {"Edit", "Delete"};
        list.setItems(dept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if(which == 0 ){
                    editReminder();
                }
                else {
                    DBHandler.getInstance(c).deleteReminder (tempReminder);
                    tasksArrayList.clear();
                    tasksArrayList = DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders();
                    upcomingReminderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });
        list.setTitle("Please Select");
        list.create();
        list.show();        
    }

    public void editReminder(){
        if (tempReminder.isLoc == 1) {
            Intent edit = new Intent(this, LocBasedReminder.class);
            edit.putExtra ("editReminder" , tempReminder);                  
            this.startActivity(edit);
        }
        else {
            Intent edit = new Intent(this, TimeBasedReminder.class);
            edit.putExtra ("editReminder" , tempReminder);                  
            this.startActivity(edit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your `tasksArrayList = DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders();` by `tasksArrayList.addAll(DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders());`

Comment: use this line before this line 
DBHandler.getInstance(c).deleteReminder (tempReminder); upcomingReminderListAdapter.remove(tempReminder);

Comment: Thanks a ton @Raphael :) it worked :)

Comment: @Khizar thanks to you too for showing your kind concern :)

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier kindly post this as answer so I may upvote it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
tasksArrayList = DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders();
```

by

```
tasksArrayList.addAll(DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are updating your `tasksArrayList` but your are not passing your updated `tasksArrayList` to your adapter. your adapter have old `tasksArrayList` with old values in it . that is why your view is not refreshing even after `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create method in your adapter which get refreshed list with items and then set notifyDataSetChanges():

For example in your adapter add this method:

```
public void notifyMyAdapter(ArrayList<ReminderItem> itemsList) {
        this.theListInYourAdapter = itemsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

In your activity just call `upcomingReminderListAdapter.notifiMyAdapter(tasksArrayList);` insead `upcomingReminderListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
...
                   if(which == 0 ){
                        editReminder();
                    }
                    else {
                        DBHandler.getInstance(c).deleteReminder (tempReminder);
                        tasksArrayList.clear();
                        tasksArrayList = DBHandler.getInstance(c).getBothReminders();
                        upcomingReminderListAdapter.notifiMyAdapter(tasksArrayList);
                    }
...
```

Hope it helps!